# Powershell: Export List of apps

Tags: list, powershell

I wanted a hands off approach to get a list of all the applications installed on a system.
A search brought me to many websites that utilized `Get-ItemProperty`  like on this page [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/165293/how-to-get-a-list-of-software-installed-on-your-pc-with-a-single-command/)

I quickly found that I could export the list to txt file for easy access at a later time.

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table –AutoSize > C:\Users\username\Documents\InstalledPrograms-PS.txt
```

*username is a place holder

What I found, however, is that I could run this when pasting it directly into powershell, but when placing this into a script, it would crash or not run at all.

I'm assuming I'm missing something and a straight copy and paste will not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

NOTE: I'm sure someone is bound to recommend `WMIC`, but this does not seem to list all the apps.

Update:
Seems that within my script

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*
```

on its own works just fine. It's when the formatting happens that it crashes.

---

**Solution:**

For anyone looking to get an easy and quick way to get a list of all applications, including microsoft store ones, here's what I did. I just have them export to a .txt file to keep for later.

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table > c:\applist.txt
```

Microsoft Store Apps

```
Get-AppxPackage | Select Name, PackageFullName |Format-Table -AutoSize > c:\microsoftlist.txt
```

Comment: It worked for me, although emacs said the '-' before AutoSize was a foreign character.  `\226`

Comment: That seems to be the problem I could not pinpoint. Everywhere I went, everyone included 'AutoSize', but that was crashing things for me. I removed 'AutoSize' alltogether and it did what it was supposed to perfectly.

Comment: -js2010 if you'd like to submit that as an answer, I'll vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me, although emacs said the '-' before AutoSize was a foreign character. \226
It may be unicode en dash, 8211 decimal:  https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm  A regular dash would be 45.

```
[int][char]'–'

8211
```

By the way, there's also `get-package` to list installed applications.

Comment: I already stated this in the comments section from the original post, but I wanted to make sure people knew why this was the chosen answer.

From js2010's comment, I realized that 'AutoSize' as a whole was causing trouble for me. By removing it, I was able to get my script working.